# Парсинг постов FB без API на Python

Tags: python, парсер, facebook

Как можно спарсить посты facebook пользователей без использования `graph-api`, на python (кроме `selenium`)?

Comment: Вручную спарсить? На счётах? На калькуляторе? На каком-то языке программирования, на худой конец?

Comment: Да, можно ‍♂️

Comment: на Python, каким образом? про selenium слышал, какие еще варианты есть? подскажите

Comment: Чем Вам селениум не угодил?

Comment: Абсолютно искусственные ограничения, для чего Вам вообще это, если не секрет?

Comment: через selenium аккаунт блокируется, какой есть менее блокируемый способ, или есть программы какие нибудь?

Comment: @Dastan, возможно вам поможет `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` из коммента к ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231002/201445

Comment: можно просто занести фейсбуку достаточно денег и они сами все упакуют и дадут (если только там нет конфликтов с законом).