# Как скрыть, что ты зашел через selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, useragent

Использую `chromedriver`. Как скрыть от сайта, что ты зашел на него при помощи Selenium?

Comment: По-моему, selenium для сайтов как честный браузер выглядит. Странно, что сайт понимает, где вы открыли его, а его через selenium. Возможно, он анализирует движение мышки

Comment: Нет, у них подгружается JS код, который определяет, что браузер используется селениумом

Answer (score 6):

Добавьте `user-agent` аргументом в `Options`, например:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

Comment: На сайте, на который я захожу, есть какая-то защита, где они распознают, что я работаю через selenium - https://imgur.com/8wnr2Sd
Смена юзер агента не помогает

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт О, обфусцировано...

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт попробуйте еще две опции: opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])  
opts.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт можно адрес сайта, который детектит селениум? ps не помогли excludeSwitches и useAutomationExtension?

Comment: @Jack_oS Мне помогло это : chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

Answer (score 4):

Я делаю так

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver  # Вебморда
from time import sleep  # Для таймаута
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # Опции селениума

while True:
    ua = UserAgent()
    opts = Options()
    us_ag = ua.random  # Меняет регулярно юзер-агенты при запросе
    url = 'https://2ip.ru'  # Сайт для проверки измененного юзерагента

    print(us_ag)

    opts.add_argument(f"user-agent={us_ag}") #  Десктопный useragent
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)  # Иногда нужно явно указать адрес 
        # web драйвера executable_path=r"F:\GIT\siteparser\seleniumparse\chromedriver.exe"

    driver.get(url)  # Открываем в браузере что бы убедиться в применении юзер-агента
    sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверить видит ли сайт использование webdriver можно [здесь](https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html)

Отключить в хроме можно так:

```
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

Посмотреть видеогайд по отключению можно [тут](https://youtu.be/KMSC1yzJRSI)

Answer (score 2):

попробуй использовать FireFox и всавить вот такой код:

```
option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
# убирает флажок что автоматизированное ПО управляет браузером
option.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
# подмена user-agent
option.set_preference("general.useragent.override", # вот сюда нужно ввести user-agent)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
```

мне это помогло

Answer (score 1):

У меня версия Chrome  97.0.4692.71 работает только этот вариант.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

EXE_PATH = r'..\chromedriver.exe'
opts = Options()

opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
opts.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts, executable_path=EXE_PATH)

driver.get('https://google.com')
time.sleep(10)
```

Хотя считается, что начиная с версии 79.0.3945.16 должен работать данный вариант:

```
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Источник: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html

Answer (score 0):

Используйте selenium stealth..
Пакет python selenium-stealth для предотвращения обнаружения. Эта программа пытается сделать python selenium более скрытным.

На данный момент selenium-stealth поддерживает только **Selenium Chrome**.

Проходит все результаты на скрытность webdriver.

Можете сами почитать (там не много) и попробовать[selenium-stealth 1.0.6](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).