Проблема с авторизацией в aliexpress.ru в окне браузера, открытом Selenium
Используя Selenium в node.js открываю окно браузера:


const {Builder, Browser} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function () {
   const url = 'https://aliexpress.ru';
   let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).build();
   await driver.get(url);
}())



Но в нём не удаётся авторизоваться на сайте. То сайт выдаёт нерешаемую капчу, то сейчас вовсе авторизация зависает после ввода пароля. С обычным окном браузера проблем нет.

Оказалось достаточно добавить в options аргумент для скрытия данных о открытии браузера через webdriver:


const {Builder, Browser} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const options = new Chrome.Options();

(async function() {
  const url = 'https://aliexpress.ru';
  let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeOptions(options.addArguments('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'))
    .build();
  await driver.get(url);
}())



Навёл на эти мысли ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1312371/591860
